# What's the difference between deallocating memory in c++ style or with garbage collector?

Tags: c++, garbage-collection

I usually hear that c++ is "faster" than every language with the garbage collector. I don't think this is the only reason, but I read that one point is that in c++ you can free memory in a faster way.

Assuming to talk only about the way that a language frees memory, is it true that, time speaking, if you destroy every object for example at the end of his scope or if the GC chooses when to do it, the first way is more fast?

Comment: Life is not just as simple as GC or not GC... there're a **lot** of different things that impact the performance of your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true, that garbage collectors have a price.

For example, in [Quantifying the Performance
of Garbage Collection vs. Explicit Memory Management](https://www.cs.umass.edu/~emery/pubs/gcvsmalloc.pdf) paper they say:

> Comparing
>   runtime, space consumption, and virtual memory footprints
>   over a range of benchmarks, we show that the runtime performance
>   of the best-performing garbage collector is competitive with explicit
>   memory management when given enough memory. In particular,
>   when garbage collection has five times as much memory
>   as required, its runtime performance matches or slightly exceeds
>   that of explicit memory management. However, garbage collection’s
>   performance degrades substantially when it must use smaller
>   heaps. With three times as much memory, it runs 17% slower on
>   average, and with twice as much memory, it runs 70% slower. Garbage
>   collection also is more susceptible to paging when physical
>   memory is scarce. In such conditions, all of the garbage collectors
>   we examine here suffer order-of-magnitude performance penalties
>   relative to explicit memory management.

Answer (score 2):

"Faster" is a very vague concept; the actual destruction of objects and deallocation of memory will be just as fast however it's instigated.

The advantages of the C++ model are that it's deterministic (destruction happens at a known time, not whenever the garbage collector gets round to it), and can have less overhead (the garbage collector needs do some work to figure out which objects are no longer in use).

The first point is the most important: it means that you can use the same techniques to manage all kinds of resources, including things like locks which must be released at the right time, not just dynamically allocated objects.

So, in C++, a dynamic object and a lock behave similarly:

```
{
    std::unique_ptr<Thing> thing(new Thing);
    do_stuff(thing);
} // automatically destroyed here (if still owned by the pointer)

{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    do_stuff();
} // automatically unlocked here (if still owned by the lock)
```

while a hypothetical garbage-collected language would treat these differently:

```
{
    Thing thing = new Thing;
    do_stuff(thing);
} // automatically destroyed at some point, probably

try {
    mutex.lock();
    do_stuff();
} finally {
    mutex.unlock();  // manually unlocked here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex subject but I can show some limit cases:

If you take C++ versus c# for example you know the difference concerning memory management is that memory is freeed

- when the Garbage Collector (GC) wants it (for C#)
- when the programmer wants it (for C++)

So if you create a program in C++ that releases memory as soon as you don't need it anymore, then the memory footprint is lower, leading to more performances.

This assumes that the cost of freeing memory is small obviously.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

No, C++ is not necessarily faster because of absence of a garbage collector.

So, at one extreme there are programs that explicitly manage their resource usage, and for which a garbage collector will be more hindrance than help.   At the other extreme is a program that does not bother much about resource management, which will probably run better if helped by a garbage collector.   In between those extremes, it depends.

The presence of a garbage collector does tend to encourage writing code that does not manage its memory all that closely.  After all, one purpose of a garbage collector is to give the programmer such freedom.   Using the same techniques, but without a garbage collector present, tends to result in a program that uses (and leaks!) more memory, and - if executed for a while - runs more slowly.   Conversely, a program written so it explicitly manages memory, because it assumes no garbage collector is present, probably won't benefit much, and may take a hit, if a garbage collector is then introduced.